# Captcha insert from subfolder

Tags: php, captcha

How can I insert generated captcha image from subfolder? In index.php there is include login.php and this login.php contains an insertion to display captcha image:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo '<images src="captcha.php?w=110&h=40&c=6" >'; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="captcha" /></td>
</tr>
```

The captcha.php generates the image, and if I call this php direct it displays the image. If I place all file next to index.php it works great, but I want separate all file in core folder except index.php.

Comment: You should not rely on filesystem for calling scripts [that's so 90ies]- use namespaces with autoloaders and a router, and everything will be kept tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the file in an absolute location.  Use the relative path instead, then all files that use this code will adjust according to server rules instead of their geographical location.

So instead of

```
src="captcha.php..."
```

use

```
src="/root/path/captcha.php..."
```

with `/root/path/` of course being wherever your documents are on the server relative to your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Doesn't work, but if I create a php file only with one line: <img src="core/captcha.php?w=100&h=40&c=6" >, it displays captcha. Maybe the includes are wrong...

Comment: That line is also using it as an absolute path.  `core/captcha.php` tells whatever file it is to look in the folder it's already in for `core`.  From what you've told us I'm guessing this won't always be the case.  If you reference it in relation to the document root, with the preceding `/` in the beginning, it will work for you unless PHP/Apache don't have access to it for some reason (which you've ruled out by saying it works for some files and not others).

Comment: I modified:
index.php: require('core/login.php');
login.php: <img src="core/captcha.php?w=100&h=40&c=6" >
And it works fine!

Comment: Yes because the `core/captcha.php` and `core/login.php` are both in relation to where `index.php` is on your server.  The act of including `login.php` simply injects the text into the running `index.php` script so none of those paths are being parsed by `login.php` or they would fail